# Как в ботнет (пиринговая сеть) добавляются новые участники?

Tags: p2p

Как в ботнет добавляются новые участники? В одноранговую пиринговую сеть. Каким образом?

Comment: а то на комьютере обнаружил такое чудо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/920178/%d0%a1%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-p2p-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%91-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0c%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8 Дубликат

Answer (score 3):

Есть разные вирусы/программы и разные способы. Начнем по процессу.

Вначале программе нужно попасть на компьютер. Тут используются разные способы:

- просто попросить пользователя запустить "обновление флеша".
- "друг принес флешку".
- "зараженная ось" или программа.
- хитрых способов, используя уязвимости.

Когда программа попала, ей нужно "окопаться" - то есть, перехитрить антивирус/фаервол/пользователя и обеспечить себе постоянный запуск.

Третий этап - объединится с себе подобными. Для этого нужно найти "командный центр". Тут также есть много разных способов.

- просто скачать нужные данные с сайта (имя может быть даже статичным).
- просканировать порты соседних машин и найти там "соседей". У них можно получить структуру сети и командный центр.

Когда данные о сети получены, можно смело работать.

Вы, скорее всего спрашиваете о первом этапе (как вирус проникает), но в вопросе звучит третий этап - как он объединяется с себе подобными.

Поэтому, скорее всего, Вы подхватили вирусняк по простой причине - через уязвимость.